# Graph and Dijkstra in python

Tags: python, dijkstra

As another homework I have to do a Dijsktra's algorithm, but I'm not sure how to create a graph and if my implementation is right.
I have to use a given pattern that look like this:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.minDistance = None
        self.previousVertex = None
        self.edges = []


class Edge:
    def __init__(self, source, target, weight):
        self.source = source
        self.target = target
        self.weight = weight


class Dijkstra:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertexes = Vertex

    def createGraph(self, vertexes, edgesToVertexes):
        pass

    def getVertexes(self):
        pass

    def computePath(self, sourceId):
        pass

    def getShortestPathTo(self, targetId):
        pass

    def resetDijkstra(self):
        pass
```

While calling a `createGraph` function it gives me two arrays: vertexes & edgesToVertexes containing `Vertexes` and `Edges`.
So how do I exactly extract data from these arrays and Initialize them as objects into both classes?

Comment: If you do not know how to access items in a `list` (what you probably mean with "array") and not know how to access an attribute of an object you should start with the Python tutorial first before doing more complicated things: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: As what you gave, if `vertexes` and `edgesToVertexes` are lists holding `Vertex` and `Edge` objects respectively, you'll have to do some sort of iteration through those lists to and connect `Vertex` with its corresponding `Edge` objects through those methods.

Comment: I know how to acces items from `list`, but I don't know how to make `Vertexes` or `Edges` from them.